# 1 vs. 1 mode on Android MK X

Tags: android, mortal-kombat-x

Is there a way to enter a simple *1 vs. 1* mode after installing the Android version of *Mortal Kombat X*?
I can't seem to find such an option. Does it need to be unlocked somehow? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_X#Gameplay) this mode exists, at least for the Windows and consoles versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is **NO** as for now. But yes you can play 1 vs 1 in pc version and in given link of yours, they are talking about pc version(as i have played pc and mobile version only) where you can use those kinds of skill, and can use parts of the environment between fight.